# Vec<u8> usage for representing strings on ink! Smart Contracts

Tags: ink

I was previously told not to use `String` in ink! contracts.

Right now I'm using `Vec<u8>` to represent strings, but I'm still feeling a bit unsure if I'm on the right path, mainly because:

- they're unbounded, which can lead to undefined behavior
- whenever I have `Vec<u8>` on some message interface, `polkadot-js` allows me to upload a file, which feels very wrong

which type is best suited to represent strings in a contract?

Answer (score 4):

If you really need a `String` in your contract then you should use a `String` type. That is the correct way to do it.

However, using strings in contracts can be considered an anti pattern. Strings are for human consumption and anything user facing should be placed in UI code.

> they're unbounded, which can lead to undefined behavior

They are not "more" unbounded as a `String`. Please note that this can not lead to undefined behavior in a contract. At some point you will hit a limit (memory allotted to your contract, gas limit) and this is completely deterministic.

Comment: the strings I need to deal with are coming into the contract as inputs from the user

Comment: As I said: If you are sure that you want to handle text in your contract then `String` is the way to go. Maybe accept this answer and ask a new question specifically about whether text handling is the right thing to do in your case.